# ERROR Summar present at the last of Valgrind Report

Tags: valgrind

I have run a valgrind check on my Application. This is the O/P I can see at the end of valgrind file.

==28497== ERROR SUMMARY: 939015 errors from 228 contexts (suppressed: 2650 from 164)

Can anyone please explain what does the below line mean

==28497== ERROR SUMMARY: 939015 errors from 228 contexts (suppressed: 2650 from 164)

A Roy -

Comment: I believe it means it found 939015 errors, though I thought it would stop reporting errors by default after 1000.  That's very high indeed.  Could perhaps post what command line you used to get this output and perhaps some of the error output?

Comment: I have used the following valgrind options   

valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --num-callers=30 --leak-resolution=low --show-reachable=yes --log-file= [log file name ]
--suppressions=[suppression.sppr] --gen-suppressions=all [binary]

Also it shows definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

But still Errors at the end